# Postgresql regexp_matches inside view always returns null when queried from PHP

Tags: php, regex, postgresql, base64

I have view similar to this one

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW regexp_test AS (
    SELECT regexp_matches(decode('NTB4', 'base64')::text, '(\d+)x')
)
```

When I query view from pgAdmin, array with single value of 50 is returned, as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM regexp_test
```

But when I call the very same query from within PHP via `pg_query('SELECT * FROM regexp_test')`, nothing is returned.

*postgres version 9.5.3,
php version 7.0.3 (same result with 5.6.14)*

PHP code is very plain:

```
<?php

$link = pg_connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres password=postgres');
$qry = "SELECT * FROM regexp_test";
$res = pg_query($link, $qry);

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($res)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP usage?

Comment: @chris85 I added minimal necessary PHP code to recreate into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out using `encode(decode('NTB4', 'base64'), 'escape')` instead of typecast `decode('NTB4', 'base64')::text` fixed problem.

So test view now looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW regexp_test AS (
    SELECT regexp_matches(encode(decode('NTB4', 'base64'), 'escape'), '(\d+)x')
)
```

Calling `pg_query('SELECT * FROM regexp_test')` now returns expected result - single row/field with `'{50}'` in it.

Answer (score 1):

The same query

```
select  e'\\x353078'::bytea;
```

gives results in different formats in **psql**:

```
  bytea
----------
 \x353078
```

and in **PgAdmin III**:

```
  bytea
----------
 50x
```

[For the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html)

> The bytea type supports two external formats for input and output: PostgreSQL's historical "escape" format, and "hex" format. Both of these are always accepted on input. The output format depends on the configuration parameter `bytea_output`; the default is hex. (Note that the hex format was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.0; earlier versions and some tools don't understand it.)

PgAdmin III (and also PgAdmin4) probably for historical reasons sets the value of `bytea_output` to `escape` while the default value of the parameter is `hex`. This can lead to confusion (and as you can see it leads). It seems that pgAdmin should not change the default value of the parameter.

You can change the parameter in your application to get the same behaviour like in PgAdmin:

```
set bytea_output to escape;
```

Of course, using `encode()` is also a good solution.

Comment: `SELECT regexp_matches(decode('NTB4', 'base64')::text, '(\d+)x')` It works when it is called via pgAdmin. Anyway thank you I got into this direction just a few minutes ago and using encode instead of ::text solved the problem.

Comment: pgAdmin III 1.22.0 - Windows - it really does.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_query` returns a result resource.

```
$result = pg_query('SELECT * FROM regexp_test');

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "$row";
}
```

[`pg_query` returns false on error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php)

> If an error occurs, and FALSE is returned, details of the error can be retrieved using the pg_last_error() function if the connection is valid.

Comment: pg_query(...) reutrns resource, pg_last_error() returns empty string.