# How to cast binary numbers to bytea?

Tags: postgresql

```
select
 '1000000011011110101111100001101101100000011100110011001100111111'::bit(64)
 as x;
```

I need to convert to other representations, like hexadecimal, base64 or used it in a function for base36 or base58 conversion... So need to cast to `bytea`. But there is no `x::bytea`, what the **simplest way to do it?**

Comment: `select to_hex('1000000011011110101111100001101101100000011100110011001100111111'::bit(64)::bigint)` and `select cast (to_hex('1000000011011110101111100001101101100000011100110011001100111111'::bit(64)::bigint) as bytea);` ?..

Comment: Thanks @VaoTsun, you show a good solution, expressing with  the `WITH` clause of Klin's anwer, `SELECT encode( cast(to_hex(val::bigint) as bytea, 'base64')`... I have no pg v10 here, it works fine for you?  And for bigger binaries, there are a "super-big datatype" (perhaps extension for arbitrary ints) to cast from super- big to `bytea`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`decode()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html)

```
with data(val) as (
values (
    '1000000011011110101111100001101101100000011100110011001100111111'::bit(64))
)

select decode(to_hex(val::bigint), 'hex')
from data;

       decode       
--------------------
 \x80debe1b6073333f
(1 row)
```

The function returns `bytea`, you can encode it as `base64`:

```
select encode(decode(to_hex(val::bigint), 'hex'), 'base64')
from data;

    encode    
--------------
 gN6+G2BzMz8=
(1 row)
```

---

**NOTE**: for bigger tham `bigint` binaries, you need to use [GMP external extension](https://dvarrazzo.github.io/pgmp/) and the `mpz` datatypes... And check if the cast to `bytea` is working fine, or use a direct conversion with GMP.

Comment: Hi, thanks klin!  About *bytea* , where it?  Example `endcode(bytea,'base64')`

Comment: oops, thanks (!), can I/you merge my wiki-answer here, to delete it?

Comment: Well, `CAST` does not seem to be a correct solution, see [SqlFiddle,](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7e263/3)

Comment: Whether the cast works properly or not depends on the current value of the `bytea_output` configuration parameter. Read more [in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41030194/1995738)